# How to fix this error:Maximum request length exceeded?

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to export a GridView to Excel file which is from an Access database so when I put this content in web.config file. Website is in asp.net with vb as back end code.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

I get server error

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: So what is this question really about? The error you state in the Question title about "Maximum request length exceeded" or the error 500 you list in the details?  Precisely when do the errors occur?   Also, what do excel and ms-access have to do with these errors?  The overall purpose of your program may not be relevant unless the errors occur when you're trying to do something specific with those components of your software.  Does the code work before you added those specific settings?

Comment: @C Perkins So basically it is like a start end timestamps that I need to put in order to query and retrieve data from MS access that data must be stored in an excel file whenever I enter a long duration the Maximum request length exceeded is thrown and when I make changes in web.config file I get the 500-Internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this piece of code the error in Web.config goes away

```
<configuration>
        <system.web>
          <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
          <customErrors mode="Off"/>
          <authentication mode="None"/>
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
          <machineKey
    validationKey="929DF4BCF13739428C8C765842BD122C653C28F688D399F216942E5438AA880B4A793C0772A51660FDA9A69B079AB3B0ADFCFC14941F5BBD673BC72E9804DF44"
    decryptionKey="0B4443E8C132884733E8B26587FFCE50562CF8CF9980BAD4813A95D54A7A369B"
    validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
    />
        </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
      </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case Internal server error is occurring because you are giving too big value for `maxrequestlength`.

Try giving value - `2097151`, If you try to set more 500 Internal server error occurred.